# How to convert PDF to SWF using PHP

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash

Is there a way to convert PDF to SWF using PHP.

Basically I need to show PDF documents inline the browser using FlexPaper and something of that kind, but NOT Adobe reader plugin. 
I need to show PDF docs so that users won't be able to download them.

Regards,
Levon

Comment: Users will always be able to download data that is in some way transferred from your server. What exactly is your motivation behind this?

Comment: I know, the thing is that there are various methods how to make that harder for the users, kind of making more obstacles ... like does FlexPaper ...

Comment: Is there any reason why your users shouldn't be aloud to download the pdf files? If you ask me, you're hindering the user experience by limiting their options.

Comment: Yeah there is ... this shouldn't be discussed as it is a requirment

Comment: Perhaps you should consider doing projects with negotiable requirements.

Comment: Oh guys please ... I just need to show the docs using stuff like flexpaper ...

Comment: I've tried pdf2swf from SWFTools and it seems to work very well.

Comment: yeah but the conversion takes too long time ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out pdf2swf from http://www.swftools.org/. It's not a PHP module but you can call it with the exec-Function.

Comment: yeah it seems to be the only reasonable solution