# View word docs and PDF in browser?

Tags: php, flash, pdf, doc

I am currently working on a site that has to have the ability for users to view documents that are uploaded, however they need to be viewable in browser.

I know there is the Google docs viewer (however this does not seem to work when trying toopen it in a fancybox overlay), but are they any other alternatives, maybe some API's that could turn them into Flash or similar, and then I could simply embed it as a swf?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is all about how the user has their browser configured. If you are serving a PDF, you should be sending it with a `Content-Type: application/pdf` and the browser will handle it however it is set up to handle it. Same goes for word docs, with the relevant MIME type. Trying to convert them to a universal format - which would basically have to be HTML - is costly in system resources and a lot of effort/messing around for little gain. It would also make it very hard to modify the documents.

Comment: As far as I understand, google is the one who servers the documents. If it works in the non fancybox way, it's headers are ok and the problem is somewhere with the javascript and the fancybox thingy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said "however this does not seem to work when trying toopen it in a fancybox overlay" Did you tried with headers :

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
```

For swf conversion see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349082/how-to-convert-pdf-to-swf-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

> but are they any other alternatives, maybe some API's that could turn
>   them into Flash or similar, and then I could simply embed it as a swf?

Yes, there are APIs for converting word and PDF documents to Flash (swf). There is also a possibility to convert them to pure HTML so that the documents are shown directly in browser without Word or PDF software (Adobe Reader, etc.). Personally I use Print2Flash utility for putting my documents online. It converts my documents to both Flash and HTML formats at the same time. I do the conversion manually but there is an API for conversion as well as I can see here: http://print2flash.com/print2flashapi.php